# using TBB for non-parallel tasks

Tags: asynchronous, threadpool, tbb

I want to get a thread-pool behavior using TBB. But whenever I read documents about TBB they always talk about parallel-for, parallel-dowhile etc. In contrast what I need is a main thread to assign tasks to a thread pool so those tasks will be executed 'on their own' - execute tasks asynchronously. Tasks here can be event handling for a GUI.

Is the TBB task scheduler appropriate for such behavior? The impression I got from task scheduler is that it's only beneficial if I have tasks that can be broken down and executed in parallel to each other.

Comment: Download the "Design Patterns" guide from http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/documentation.php. It specifically mentions offloading long-running tasks from the GUI thread (see Chapter 8, "GUI Thread"), and has a simple example showing how it's done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting from version 3.0, TBB has support for asynchronous execution of tasks. For that, a special work offering method `tbb::task::enqueue()` was added. Unlike `tbb::task::spawn()`, this method guarantees that the enqueued task will be executed even if the originating thread never enters a task dispatch method such as `wait_for_all()`.

A short usage example for `task::enqueue()`:

```
class MyTask : public tbb::task {
    /*override*/ tbb::task* execute() {
        // Do the job
        return NULL; // or a pointer to a new task to be executed immediately
    }
};

MyTask* t = new (tbb::task::allocate_root()) MyTask();
tbb::task::enqueue(*t);
// Do other job; the task will be executed asynchronously
```

As @JimMishell mentioned in the comment, an example how to use it for handling of GUI events  can be found in "Design Patterns"; and the formal description of the method is available in the Reference manual (see [TBB documentation](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/documentation-0) for both).